# SublimeText2: How do I include some method/Class and have Sublime suggest it to me?

Tags: python, autocomplete, sublimetext2

I am using `SQLAlchemy` with `Sublime Text2` and I did the following

```
from sqlalchemy import Column
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

Base = declarative_base()
# engine = create_engine('sqlite:///:memory:', echo=True)


class Transaction(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'transaction'
    id = Column()
```

I want Sublime to see my imports/site-packages and suggest me to import it like what IntelliJ IDEA and Eclipse does.
Does Sublime Text2 support this intelligence?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The [Sublime CodeIntel plugin](https://github.com/Kronuz/SublimeCodeIntel) provides this functionality for you.  Installation instructions at link.

Comment: I have added the new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15302739/sublimetext2-sublimecodeintel-doesnt-adds-import-even-when-it-suggests