# SublimeText2: SublimeCodeIntel doesn't adds import even when it suggests

Tags: python, autocomplete, sublimetext2, sublimetext

I am trying to use `SQLAlchemy` with `SublimeText2` and I do the following sequence

[image]

Then I do
[image]
and then
[image]

so my code is

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base


Base = declarative_base()


class Transaction(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'transaction'
    # id = Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True)
    id = Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True)


def main():
    print 'Hello World!'


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

When I try to build this as python build i see

```
line 10, in Transaction
    id = Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True)
NameError: name 'Column' is not defined
[Finished in 0.2s with exit code 1]
```

This is because it does not imports the `Column`, `Integer` in the file

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

My understanding is that SublimeCodeIntel will parse the modules you have imported and make suggestions based on what you've imported. From their [github page](https://github.com/Kronuz/SublimeCodeIntel):

> Imports autocomplete - Shows autocomplete with the available modules/symbols in real time.

I don't see anywhere in their documentation where they say it will automatically import modules for you nor have I ever found that functionality myself as I've used it in Sublime Text.

As a side note, using the PyDev plugin with either Aptana Studio or Eclipse gives you a lot of functionality with respect to imports and auto completion, among other things. Granted, you're now using a full blown IDE as opposed to a lightweight text editor, but there are certainly pros and cons to both.

Comment: This is correct; the author of the question has misunderstood what SublimeCodeIntel does for him.