# Sublime text2 and autocomplete for python

Tags: python-3.x, autocomplete, sublimetext2

I am new to Sublime and I find it great and really powerful.

I like most of its features but its lacking one or I cannot find it.

When I create a class e.g.:

```
class person:
    def __init__(self, hair, height):
        self.hair = hair
        self.height = height
```

and then I assign it :

```
george  = person('black', 1.70)
```

When I try to select one of George's attributes by writing `george.` normally in an IDE I will get a list of its attributes. But now I get nothing, no list.

Is there a way to fix this problem?

Comment: Answers to similar questions on SO suggest using the CodeIntel plugin for sublime, although none of those other questions have any accepted answers. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15301477/sublimetext2-how-do-i-include-some-method-class-and-have-sublime-suggest-it-to

Comment: Nope installed CodeIntel and again no autocompletion for my classes. When i create a new instance 'jack' from my person class in the dot normally when i should see a pop up with all its attributes i see nothing. When i hit tab instead of seeing its attributes it reverts to jackself. Also i see a C:\Python32\python.exe error: Cannot find '__main__' modue in ''. Maybe thats the cause

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for python use sublime rope. code intel read this https://github.com/SublimeCodeIntel/SublimeCodeIntel#configuring